# Automatically map contents of REST JSON body as flat table in Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

With the Copy Data transformation it is possible to retrieve data from a REST call (array with flat json objects, similar to Odata) and copy the contents to a flat table keeping the data types from the source but without the necessity to set the schema for that specific data.

When I try to recreate this with Data Flow, I can't get this to work. When I check the Data Preview of my Source I get a hierarchy with a body (with my odata like data) and a header. And if I send that to my sink (Avro) it will be saved in this same hierarchical structure (including the header). I know I can fix this manually by using a Select operation (body.column1, body.column2, etc.), but I want to make my Data Flow dynamic so I'm able to use it with multiple tables/endpoints.

So I receive it like this with my REST source:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH77Y.png)

And I want it to be like this at my Sink without hardcoding my schema:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmSM3.png)

The only work around I can come up with is retrieving the data using Copy Data, put it somewhere temporarily and then use my data flow to further transform the data. Is there a more easy way to do this? I cannot imagine that I'm the only one that has this issue.

Hopefully it's clear and somebody is able to help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data flow projection will get schema from API including body and header. Hence, when you use auto mapping everything going to be saved.

Below work arounds you can think of,

1. As you mentioned, using copy data first and then data flow to further transform.
2. Use select or derived column transformations and transform your data to get all column names and then finally use sink. For this you can opt with Column pattern matching syntax. So that one condition can be meet with multiple columns to transform.
   Check below link to know about column pattern mappings.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wasn't able to manage it completely, but in another stage of my process I used option 2 and that solved the issue. Option 1 I already tried and didn't give me the results I desired.